# Show Parent category and Subcategory

Tags: plugin-development

I need to show sub category in below to the respective parent category in wordpress Sidebar.

Without using plugin I need to show the parent category and its sub categories in sidebar with following manner

```
Category1

     --Sub1

     --Sub2

Category2

   --Cat2Sub1

   --Cat2Sub2
```